# Training LUIS with names

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to train my LUIS application to recognize user names. For that I've created a Simple Entity named ContactEntity and I have added different utterances:

[intent definition with entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXjko.png)

I've trained my application but it still doesn't recognize other names, although names already labeled are perfectly recognized.

[test console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKpTB.png)

How many utterances do I have to enter to make LUIS start recognizing it?
Is it ok to use Simple Entity or should I use another type of Entity?

Thank you in advance,
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to use your ContactEntity, and because a user name could basically be anything, A better way of going about this is probably a list entity.

You can populate the list entity with user names from your database and Luis will be able to pick them up from there.

Edit: If you want Luis to recognise new contact names, continue using simple entities but focus the utterance training on the structure of the phrases. For example if you add enough "My username is [ContactEntity]" you can get Luis to pick up on future contact entities with a similar phrase structure.

Comment: Can you ellaborate on your answer.

Comment: From the documentation "Unlike other entity types, additional values for list entities aren't discovered during training", which means that I would have to enter every possible value in the list. As you said, a name can be anything, so this approach isn't valid for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Phrase Lists, for example names, and introduce all names separed by comas:
Niall, Jhon, etc....
And after that, you also need to create an Entity, type Hierarchical:
Person::Name
Finally, you have to mak the name like a Person::Name entity.

Good luck!